# Strapi Json data not coming in right format from wysiwyg

Tags: strapi

Using Strapi as headless cms when i am adding the content into wysiwyg editor.
But throgh the rest service it gives the data in unformatted string

"description": "**test**",

Since it is bold but showing the **

it should be  like that

Answer (score 0):

So far strapi doesn't have WYSIWYG fully supported, they do have a markdown editor with a nice preview.

So, when you save your data in the database, it actually saves it as markdown, so on the frontend you should parse that content into HTML, we use this package: [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked)

Perhaps you can use afterFetch mode's lifecycle and parse that content before it's sent back the the front-end: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/guides/models.html#lifecycle-callbacks

Or if you use node in your front, you can use that same package, we use angular7 and we use that library I linked before:

```
import marked from 'marked';
this.parsedContent = marked(this.article.content);
```

Then use `parsedContent` in the element container.

Notes:

- Here's a roadmap on strapi features to be implemented: https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/tabs/2-under-consideration
- And here's a direct link for the WYSIWYG support: https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/c/37-wysiwyg-html-editor, you can then vote on it to determine its importance.

Let me know if this helped or if I got something wrong.

Cheers!